# How to create features based on month-year and count in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Let's say I have a dataset with data from the last 5 months for some people. I want to create some features related to each of those 5 months, like that:

My initial dataframe is looking like that:

| Person | date |
| --- | --- |
| Person A | 25-01-2015 |
| Person B | 29-01-2015 |
| Person A | 13-02-2015 |
| Person A | 14-05-2015 |
| Person A | 19-05-2015 |

I want my dataframe to look like that from below:
So, creating 5 (or more columns, maybe 12 corresponding to all of the 12 months from 2015 year) related to month and year (grouping by the month and year) and then putting in the corresponding features their count based on the month and year.

| Person | 01-2015 | 02-2015 | 03-2015 | 04-2015 | 05-2015 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| Person B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Could you please suggest me how to do that?

Comment: Are you sure the output for (Person 1, 01-2015) is 2?

Comment: Sorry, it's 1 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pivot`:

```
out = df.groupby(['Person', pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='date')], as_index=False) \
       .size().pivot('Person', 'date', 'size')

out = out.reindex(columns=pd.date_range(out.columns.min(), out.columns.max(), freq='MS')) \
         .fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
          2015-01-01  2015-02-01  2015-03-01  2015-04-01  2015-05-01
Person                                                              
Person A           1           1           0           0           2
Person B           1           0           0           0           0
```

Comment: @stephsmith. Can you check is what you expect, please?

Comment: Yes. How do we proceed if I want to add another feature to the initial dataset? Like "number of fruits" per each month? How this code will change?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69796820/create-new-features-based-on-datetime-and-other-columns